# mysql query to select href value begins with / and filtering /sites

Tags: mysql

Hello everyone below is my schema and queries. you can try out here https://paiza.io/projects/AVb-EGBcX6d76NyiLFgzAw?language=mysql .

```
create table Test(id integer, body_value longtext);
insert into Test(id, body_value) values(1, 'Abc href="/sites" cdef href="/app"');
insert into Test(id, body_value) values(2, 'bcdef href="/" ghjhgj cdef href="/sites"');
insert into Test(id, body_value) values(3, 'Dog  href="https" jhgj href="/sites" jh l href="/cdef"');
insert into Test(id, body_value) values(4, 'href="https" jhgj href="/sites" jh l');
insert into Test(id, body_value) values(5, 'Dog  href="?jhjhj" jhgj href="/sites" jh l');
select * from Test;
```

"href=/site" is present in all the line but I want href begins with / other than /sites.

id 1 and 3 has href="/app", href="/cdef"  along with 
"href=/site".

I want to match "%href=/%" but not "%href=/site%". I am expecting my output has id 1, 3.

Comment:  This is an “I want a pony” question and is too broad, making it off-topic on Stack Overflow. You’ll need to make an attempt show your code so we can understand what you’re trying to do on a technical level. Even a small amount of code can quickly get to the core of your problem and help us understand where you’re coming from.

If you really don't know where to start or need guidance and support consider mentoring or coaching try services like [Codementor](https://www.codementor.io), [Savvy](https://www.savvy.is), [Hackhands](https://hackhands.com), or [airpair](https://www.airpair.com).

Answer (score 0):

I guess I would check if href="/sites" is present before or after href="/_%".

```
(body_value LIKE '%href="/sites"%href="/_%"' OR body_value LIKE '%href="/_%"%href="/sites"%')
```